# Can Django Tenant Schema work with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a SaaS app with Django, Django Tenant Schema and Django Rest Framework. Everything works fine without an API but I have issues with sending a get request to different Tenants via an API call. It returns users from all the tenants in the database even if I specify the subdomain.

However, a get request to a none API endpoint works fine, in fact, everything done outside the API endpoint works great.

For Example:

`http://goldlimited.localhost:8000/dashboard/api/users`

Returns the same information as

`http://missinglinkgm.localhost:8000/dashboard/api/users`

The view is a basic ModelViewSet

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.filter()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

And the Serializer

```py
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ("password",)
```

And Route

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('user', UserViewSet, 'user')
```

I am wondering if there is a configuration I am missing to make DRF work with Django Tenant Schema.

Comment: I've recently added `django-tenants` to my project which uses DRF and I'm not seeing the issue you describe, model instances from one tenant are not showing up in responses of another tenant. I have `django-rest-framework` listed under my `SHARED_APPS`. Could you post what your `MIDDLEWARE` setting looks like?

Comment: I figured out I was using the old django-tenant schemas project. I switched to the new project that has active support and it works fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does work, little bit of tweaking to settings.py would work. Make sure you add `rest_framework` to **INSTALLED, TENANT** APPS.

```py
SHARED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',
    'Client',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # include below if you need admin panel on main site(public schema)    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',

    # include other apps here
    # 'rest_framework' # if needed or if you're handling auth 
]

TENANT_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # include below if you need admin panel on every tenant    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',

     # include other apps here
    'rest_framework', # mandatory
]
```